# Solve an equation where a determinant of a 3x3 matrix is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Hello! I'm trying to solve
$$\left|\begin{matrix} x^3-1 & x^2-1 & x - 1\\ x^3-8 & x^2-4 & x - 2 \\ x^3-27 & x^2-9 & x - 3 \end{matrix}\right| = 0.$$
(see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwQWy.png)). Essentially, it is a determinant of a 3x3 matrix that is equal to zero.

I think I need to take advantage of the properties of a zero determinant (has infinite solutions) and replace x with something else.... That way, the system gets way less complex and I will be able to do Gauss elimination and what not... I've tried though changing x to a bunch of things (2x, x^2, √x etc) but i cant seem to find a pattern.

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated ^^

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If you expand the determinant it would result in a polynomial of high degree. However, it is possible to see some factors before that. Observe that the entries of the first row are all multiplies of $x-1$. So, that factor can come out of the determinant. Similarly $x-2$ is a common factor of the entries of the second row, and $x-3$ of the third two.

Comment: You get $0=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\det\begin{pmatrix}x^2+x+1&x+1&1\\x^2+2x+4&x+2&1\\x^2+3x+9&x+3&1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @user85667 thanks a lot ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously $x = 1$, $x = 2$ and $x = 3$ are solutions. Moreover, by subtracting the first row from the second and the third, we arrive at the equation
$$\left|\begin{matrix} x^3-1 & x^2-1 & x - 1\\ -7 & -3 & -1 \\ -26 & -8 & -2 \end{matrix}\right| = 0.$$
This determinant is now evidently a polynomial of degree $3$. As we already found three roots, these are all solutions to the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the question by applying Row and Column properties. In your question as far as I can see you can apply R_1=R_2-R_1. And also you can apply R_2=R_3-R_2 . Then compute the determinant to 0.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: But where I will get the option of MathJax formatting in MSE? Kindly inform me

Comment: Did you actually click on the links from my previous comment?

Comment: Yes. I have understood now.

Comment: Actually I was thinking that there might be any app for that.